# MVC 5 Html.ValidationSummary is not showing error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I am manually adding the following Model Error in my controller,

```
ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "An error occurred");
```

However when the view is loaded, the `@Html.ValidationSummary(true)` is not showing any errors.

I have also tried `@Html.ValidationSummary(false)`.

I have read many articles on this behavior and I have tried all the suggestions with no luck.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you show what your code currently looks like, when using AddModelError

Comment: It is my second line in my question above.

Comment: the reason we ask for more code is to help discover those errors. Everything you showed should have been correct, so it was likely an issue in the controller code surrounding that AddModelError (as you later discovered)

Answer (score 2):

I can see it work. See the sample here: http://dotnetfiddle.net/Jz7wQj

Answer (score 0):

Beware when using custom `ViewData` objects.

### Problem Reproduced

**Model**

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace BrokenValidationSummaryTest.Models
{
    public class MyModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string Whatever { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
using BrokenValidationSummaryTest.Models;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace BrokenValidationSummaryTest.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Submit(MyModel postedData)
        {
            return View(viewName: "Index", model: postedData);
        }
    }
}
```

**View "Index"**

```
@model BrokenValidationSummaryTest.Models.MyModel

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="carrier-tabs">
    <li class="active">
        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#search" class="tab-level-1" data-tab-name="search">Search</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="search" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        @Html.Partial(partialViewName: "TabBody", model: Model, viewData: new ViewDataDictionary())
    </div>
</div>
```

**View "TabBody"**

```
@model BrokenValidationSummaryTest.Models.MyModel

@Html.ValidationSummary(excludePropertyErrors: false)

<h2>TabBody</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm(actionName: "Submit", controllerName: "Home", method: FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <div>Whatever:</div>
        <div>@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Whatever)</div>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    }
```

### Explanation

The partial view has the ValidationSummary HTML helper.  We pass a custom ViewData object to the partial view.  This custom ViewData object passed to the partial view does not contain the ViewState found in the view 'Index'.  The HTML helper ValidationSummary does not have enough required information to render the error messages properly.

**Recommendation**: if using custom ViewData, populate the custom ViewData with the ViewState of the parent view.